# Initializing array as is vs doing array.push(item) in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there any performance difference between doing:

```js
const array = [1, 2]
```

and

```js
const array = []
array.push(1);
array.push(2);
```

I think the latter is more readable. I read that array.push() is faster in some browsers compared to doing array[n] = item, but did not find anything about initializing with the element as is. Are they both O(1) operations? Is there a downside to doing the latter?

Comment: Why are you worrying about this? Choose one or the other. If you think option 2 is more readable use that. Premature optimisation is a pointless exercise. But, personally, I would go for option 1.

Comment: Performance-wise: no difference. If you worry, benchmark it! But I have to disagree that the latter with mutations is more readable.

Comment: The former is MUCH more readable to people who know what an array is.

Comment: There are some neat tools, like [jsbench.me](https://jsbench.me/), which make quickly testing stuff like this really easy, without having to write your own benchmark. But if you're unsure, I've written a benchmarking script [an answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72220336/979052). Hope it helps..

Answer (score 3):

The first method (`const array = [1, 2]`) is more performant, as there are fewer operations.

After running a quick benchmark to back this up, it appears that the second method is 95% slower! (based on approximately 736026k ops per sec, as opposed to 27184k ops per sec)

---

Here's a rudimentary demo which outputs how long (in milliseconds) that it takes to run each operation 1 million times.

```js
const NUM_ITTERATIONS = 1000000;

// TC 1: Initializing an Array
function testCase1() {
 const array = [1, 2]
}

// TC 2: Using Array.push()
function testCase2() {
 const array = []
  array.push(1);
  array.push(2);
}

// Start timer, run given function x time, then end timer
const runPerformanceTest = (testCase, msg) => {
  const startTime = performance.now();
  let n = 0;
  while (n < NUM_ITTERATIONS) {
    testCase();
    n++;
  }
  const endTime = performance.now();
  const totalTime = endTime - startTime;
  console.log(`${msg}: ${totalTime} ms`);
}

// Kick of the test for each function + print results
runPerformanceTest(testCase1, 'Test Case 1');
runPerformanceTest(testCase2, 'Test Case 2');
```

Alternatively, here's a longer benchmark: https://jsbench.me/msl33e4b6k/1

Comment: What browser are you using? I cannot reproduce a 95% difference (even with more iterations). Also, beware of [microbenchmarks](https://mrale.ph/blog/2012/12/15/microbenchmarks-fairy-tale.html) - you'll need to `return array` (or even better assign it to a global variable), otherwise the `const` initialisation will be completely optimised away and you'll measure only an empty loop.

Comment: I'm using Firefox, but also get a similar result in Brave: It's outputting: `Test Case 1: 3.5 ms` and `Test Case 2: 17.3` for me. But I am aware this is terribly inaccurate given the browsers optimizations, and the tiny size of the loop. But it's the best I could include in a runnable snippet.